# postgresql duplicate key violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql

I have a question I know this was posted many times but I didn't find an answer to my problem. The problem is that I have a table and a column "id" I want it to be unique number just as normal. This type of column is serial and the next value after each insert is coming from a sequence so everything seems to be all right but it still sometimes shows this error. I don't know why. In the documentation, it says the sequence is foolproof and always works. If I add a UNIQUE constraint to that column will it help? I worked before many times on Postres but this error is showing for me for the first time. I did everything as normal and I never had this problem before. Can you help me to find the answer that can be used in the future for all tables that will be created? Let's say we have something easy like this:

```
CREATE TABLE comments
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  some_column text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE interesting.comments OWNER TO postgres;
```

If i add:

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD CONSTRAINT id_id_key UNIQUE(id)
```

Will if be enough or is there some other thing that should be done?

Comment: Show the code that's inserting the data; having the primary key will already force a unique constraint, so you don't need to add that.

Answer (score 290):

[This article explains](http://hcmc.uvic.ca/blogs/index.php?blog=22&p=8105&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) that your sequence might be out of sync and that you have to manually bring it back in sync.

**An excerpt from the article in case the URL changes:**

> If you get this message when trying to insert data into a PostgreSQL
> database:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key violates unique constraint
```

> That likely means that the primary key sequence in the table you're
> working with has somehow become out of sync, likely because of a mass
> import process (or something along those lines). Call it a "bug by
> design", but it seems that you have to manually reset the a primary
> key index after restoring from a dump file. At any rate, to see if
> your values are out of sync, run these two commands:

```
SELECT MAX(the_primary_key) FROM the_table;   
SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence(the_table, the_primary_key));
```

> If the first value is higher than the second value, your sequence is
> out of sync. Back up your PG database (just in case), then run this command:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence(the_table, the_primary_key, (SELECT MAX(the_primary_key) FROM the_table)+1);
```

> That will set the sequence to the next available value that's higher
> than any existing primary key in the sequence.

Comment: For me, I didn't know how to get "the_primary_key_sequence" -- you can see in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18233092/1370384) that you can use a method called `pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'field_name')` to get this to work.

Comment: Sure enough this fixed it - anyone have any insight on how these can get out of sync though?

Comment: `SELECT setval('the_primary_key_sequence', (SELECT MAX(the_primary_key) FROM the_table)+1);` may not be fully correct. If the MAX(the_primary_key) value is for example 9 and nextval item is 9, it is enough to run `SELECT setval('the_primary_key_sequence', (SELECT MAX(the_primary_key) FROM the_table));`. This would automatically produce nextval sequence incrementation. If you add +1, result would be jumping one sequence.

Awesome answer! Helped me to resolve this issue!

Comment: if in doubt how your sequence is called, call SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
if you use multiple schemas, keep in mind that sequences are unique per schema, so unless your sequence is in public schema you need to call SELECT nextval('schema.sequence_name'); to get it

Comment: Just to be clear the command is: `SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table', 'id'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)+1);` thanks @user

Comment: what is `'the_primary_key_sequence'` supposed to be replaced with?

Comment: ^ To answer my own question, you do this to find it: `\d "table_name";`

Comment: @P.V. you can also get `the_primary_key_sequence` via: `SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('the_table', 'the_primary_key')`

Comment: Hi. In case the queries weren't making sense to anyone, let me give an example to hopefully help:
My table showed sid as Primary key, so I used this query to check the max primary key:
`MAX(sid) FROM schema_name.table_name;`
-sid is a column in my table and represents the primary key.
-schema_name is the schema my table is located.
-table_name is the name of the table throwing the duplicate key error.

This is what I ran to check the next value of primary key sequence:
`SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('schema_name.table_name', 'sid'));`

I hope this is of some sort of help.

Comment: To everyone who is curious how this can happen! I had  `pg_catalog.setval('public.page_id_seq', 144842, true);`  in my backup file.

Comment: The linked article requires signing in with username and password, Do you have an alternative source?

Comment: @Papooch http://web.archive.org/web/20140328105619/http://hcmc.uvic.ca/blogs/index.php?blog=22&p=8105&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

Comment: pg_get_serial_sequence returns null for me.

Comment: I have removed `the_primary_key_sequence` and replaced with actual code. Now only the `the_table` and `the_primary_key` name need to be replaced to run the actual query.

Comment: One more example for this answer. 
Find out current max ID:
`SELECT MAX(id) FROM public.the_table;`
Set found max ID value as a new nexvalue (it's 1000 in this example):
`SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.the_table','id'),1000);`
Check if it's correct now:
`SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.the_table', 'id')) as new_id;`

Comment: By the way, Postgres does not make any guarantee about PRIMARY KEY order. In my case, the primary keys were out of order, had some gaps, and the sequence was LOWER*, not higher. Once I incremented out of the gap in my PRIMARY KEY values, I started getting the error.

Answer (score 59):

### Intro

I also encountered this problem and the solution proposed by @adamo was basically the right solution. However, I had to invest a lot of time in the details, which is why I am now writing a new answer in order to save this time for others.

### Case

My case was as follows: There was a table that was filled with data using an app. Now a new entry had to be inserted manually via SQL. After that the sequence was out of sync and no more records could be inserted via the app.

### Solution

As mentioned in the answer from @adamo, the sequence must be synchronized manually. For this purpose the name of the sequence is needed. For Postgres, the name of the sequence can be determined with the command `PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE`. Most examples use lower case table names. In my case the tables were created by an ORM middleware (like Hibernate or Entity Framework Core etc.) and their names all started with a capital letter.

In an e-mail from 2004 ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/28121.1098940366%40sss.pgh.pa.us)) I got the right hint.

(*Let's assume for all examples, that `Foo` is the table's name and `Foo_id` the related column.*)

Command to get the sequence name:

```
SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('"Foo"', 'Foo_id');
```

So, the table name must be in double quotes, surrounded by single quotes.

#### 1. Validate, that the sequence is out-of-sync

```
SELECT CURRVAL(PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('"Foo"', 'Foo_id')) AS "Current Value", MAX("Foo_id") AS "Max Value" FROM "Foo";
```

When the `Current Value` is less than `Max Value`, your sequence is out-of-sync.

#### 2. Correction

```
SELECT SETVAL((SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('"Foo"', 'Foo_id')), (SELECT (MAX("Foo_id") + 1) FROM "Foo"), FALSE);
```

Comment: This worked for me. There was some glitch with importing a table which caused the id_seq to go out of sync. This solution fixed it for me.

Comment: is there a script that could do that dynamically?  replace Foo with all tables , Foo_id with all primary keys

Comment: I received `currval of sequence "request_request_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session` and had to used `SELECT last_value FROM <sequence_name>;`

Comment: Very useful especially for finding the sequence name.

Comment: What if my sequence is not out of sync? I have max value 1255214 and current value 1255216

Comment: So helpful! On supabase the sequence name to use was: `'public.names_id_seq'` for a table `names` with column `id`

Comment: i fix the problem but after of time i got same error.... exist one way that postgres will get always max ID?

Comment: What does FALSE for in the correction query?

If I change to TRUE only the validate query returns the correct sequence for Current & Max Value

Answer (score 29):

> Replace the `table_name` to your actual name of the table.

1. Gives the current last id for the table. Note it that for next step.

```sql
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name;
```

2. Get the next id sequence according to postgresql. Make sure this id is higher than the current max id we get from step 1

```sql
SELECT nextVal('"table_name_id_seq"');
```

3. if it's not higher than then use this step 3 to update the next sequence.

```
SELECT setval('"table_name_id_seq"', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name)+1);
```

Answer (score 6):

[Referrence - https://www.calazan.com/how-to-reset-the-primary-key-sequence-in-postgresql-with-django/](https://www.calazan.com/how-to-reset-the-primary-key-sequence-in-postgresql-with-django/)

I had the same problem try this:
`python manage.py sqlsequencereset table_name`

Eg:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset auth
```

you need to run this in production settings(if you have)
and you need Postgres installed to run this on the server

Comment: Thanks. This saved my life + time both. Just`python manage.py sqlsequencereset app_name | python manage.py dbshell` and it's done.

Answer (score 5):

The primary key is already protecting you from inserting duplicate values, as you're experiencing when you get that error. Adding another unique constraint isn't necessary to do that.

The "duplicate key" error is telling you that the work was not done because it would produce a duplicate key, not that it discovered a duplicate key already commited to the table.

Answer (score 5):

For future searchs, use ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING.

Comment: what if I already have an on conflict on another column which is not the primary key

Comment: You can specify column names, indexes or constraint name.

Example:

    ON CONFLICT (column_name)

reference: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html

Note: Prior to PostgreSQL 7.3, serial implied UNIQUE. This is no longer automatic. If you wish a serial column to be in a unique constraint or a primary key, it must now be specified, same as with any other data type.

Answer (score 1):

**In my case carate table script is:**

```
CREATE TABLE public."Survey_symptom_binds"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Survey_symptom_binds_id_seq"'::regclass),
    survey_id integer,
    "order" smallint,
    symptom_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT "Survey_symptom_binds_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**SO:**

```
SELECT nextval('"Survey_symptom_binds_id_seq"'::regclass),
       MAX(id) 
  FROM public."Survey_symptom_binds"; 
  
SELECT nextval('"Survey_symptom_binds_id_seq"'::regclass) less than MAX(id) !!!
```

**Try to fix the proble:**

```
SELECT setval('"Survey_symptom_binds_id_seq"', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM public."Survey_symptom_binds")+1);
```

Good Luck every one!

Answer (score 1):

As @adamo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4448340/2064098) explains, `nextval(..)` can be out of sync and no longer incrementing upon the max value.  In my case it was due to a logical replication and switch-over, where PostgreSQL [leaves all sequence numbers as they were at subscription time.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-restrictions.html)

For larger databases, here are some convenient functions for querying which integer primary keys are out of sync, and to update them.

### Verify

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION primary_id_sequences_from_all_tables()
RETURNS TABLE (table_name TEXT, column_name TEXT, data_type TEXT, max BIGINT, next BIGINT) AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        SELECT tc.table_name, kcu.column_name, c.data_type
        FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
            ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
            AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
        JOIN information_schema.columns AS c
            ON kcu.table_name = c.table_name
            AND kcu.column_name = c.column_name
            AND c.data_type IN ('smallint', 'integer', 'bigint', 'decimal', 'numeric', 'real', 'double precision')
        WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    LOOP
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_nullable(rec.table_name) || ', ' || quote_nullable(rec.column_name) || ', ' || quote_nullable(rec.data_type) || ', (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(' || rec.column_name || '), 0)::BIGINT FROM ' || rec.table_name || '), (SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence(' || quote_nullable(rec.table_name) || ', ' || quote_nullable(rec.column_name) || ')))';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

n.b., the function calls `nextval` which will have a side-effect of incrementing the sequence values.  It shouldn't be a problem, but if you want to avoid this you can switch this to `pg_sequence_last_value`.  However this may only show primary keys for which `nextval` has already been called.

Call the function to verify the list:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, max, next, (max - next) AS diff
  FROM primary_id_sequences_from_all_tables()
  WHERE next IS NOT NULL AND max > next
  ORDER BY diff DESC;
```

### Update

*If you are satisfied* and wish at your own risk to fudge the `nextval()` to be `max(..) + 1` for all those columns you can run this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fixup_primary_id_sequences_in_all_tables()
RETURNS TABLE (table_name TEXT, column_name TEXT, max BIGINT, next BIGINT, set_to BIGINT) AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        SELECT seqs.table_name, seqs.column_name, seqs.max, seqs.next
        FROM primary_id_sequences_from_all_tables() AS seqs
        WHERE seqs.next IS NOT NULL AND seqs.max > seqs.next
    LOOP
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_nullable(rec.table_name) || ', ' || quote_nullable(rec.column_name) || ', ' || rec.max || '::BIGINT, ' || rec.next || '::BIGINT, setval(pg_get_serial_sequence(' || quote_nullable(rec.table_name) || ', ' || quote_nullable(rec.column_name) || '), (SELECT MAX(' || rec.column_name || ') FROM ' || rec.table_name || ')+1) AS set_to';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

... with this line:

```
SELECT * FROM fixup_primary_id_sequences_in_all_tables()
```

Comment: This was amazing. Take my upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was because of the type of my relations. I had a table property which related to both states and cities. So, at first I had a relation from property to states as OneToOne, and the same for cities. And I had the same error "duplicate key violates unique constraint". That means that: I can only have one property related to one state and city. But that doesnt make sense, because a city can have multiple properties. So the problem is the relation. The relation should be ManyToOne. Many properties to One city

Answer (score -1):

Table name started with a capital letter if tables were created by an ORM middleware (like Hibernate or Entity Framework Core etc.)

```
SELECT setval('"Table_name_Id_seq"', (SELECT MAX("Id") FROM "Table_name") + 1)
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM  (SELECT CURRVAL(PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('"Table_name"', 'Id')) AS seq, MAX("Id") AS max_id
               FROM "Table_name") AS seq_table
        WHERE seq > max_id
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

try that CLI

it's just a suggestion to enhance the adamo code (thanks a lot adamo)

```
SELECT setval('tableName_columnName_seq', (SELECT MAX(columnName) FROM tableName));
```

Answer (score -3):

For programatically solution at Django. Based on [Paolo Melchiorre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276535/2120931), I [wrote a chunk as a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68090967/2120931) to be called before any .save()

```py
from django.db import connection
def setSqlCursor(db_table):
    sql = """SELECT pg_catalog.setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"""+db_table+"""', 'id'), MAX(id)) FROM """+db_table+""";"""
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score -16):

I have similar problem but I solved it by removing all the foreign key in my Postgresql