# duplicate key value violates unique constraint Laravel and Postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-6

I try to add a new value to db, but I got this error.

> SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value
>   violates unique constraint "lkp_locations_pkey"↵DETAIL:  Key
>   **(id)=(1)** already exists. (SQL: insert into "lkp_locations" ("tex...

If I Replay the XHR ,the ID is increased, until I have an ID available ,and then the value is stored. From what I read is something about Postgres, but I am not sure what to change. [Link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448340/postgresql-duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint)

```
$lkp_abode->fill([
      'text' => $request->lkp_abode_text,
])->save();
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement

Comment: Theoretically, but I am not sure what to modify in Laravel.