# PostgreSQL Databases

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have created a table 'DayPass':

```
CREATE TABLE DayPass (
    memberNo INT PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY (memberNo) REFERENCES DayPass(memberNo),
    startDate Date,
    numberDays INT,
    price VARCHAR(30),
    check(numberDays > 0)
);
```

I am trying to insert these values:

```
INSERT INTO DayPass (memberNo, startDate, numberDays, price)
VALUES (3, '2022-01-01', '5', '£9.99');
INSERT INTO DayPass
VALUES (3, '2022-02-01', '5', '£9.99');
INSERT INTO DayPass
VALUES (3, '2022-03-01', '£5', '£9.99');
SELECT * FROM DayPass;
```

but Postgres gives me an error:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "daypass_pkey"

if am unsure where i am going wrong

Comment: Can you provide the table definition?

Comment: Please provide the table's DDL. How is the constraint "daypass_pkey"defined? And why price is a varchar-column ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE DayPass (
memberNo INT PRIMARY KEY,
FOREIGN KEY (memberNo) REFERENCES DayPass(memberNo),
startDate Date, 
numberDays INT,
price VARCHAR(30),
check(numberDays >0)
);

Comment: I was unsure of how to add the '£' to the price section as it was a must that I have the currency values on my prices

Comment: ALTER TABLE DayPass
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_DayPass
PRIMARY KEY (startDate);

Comment: i needed to make startdate a PK also so I created this constraint

Comment: The currency should be another column and of course, not a symbol of the currency,but its ISO-code

Comment: How would i go about doing that please?

Comment: Hello, im sure the problem is your primary key is not a sequence, please take a look to this question/answer

https://stackoverflow.com/q/4448340/9053821

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a column or group of columns that have values that uniquely identify a record. Neither `memberNo` or `startDate` on their own meet that criteria. You could create a PK over both `(memberNo, startDate)` or create a separate column that uses a sequence to generate unique values. See `GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY` here [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).