# How do I use var into query request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Hello i'm struggling with using variables that I declared into my jquery request:

```
var int_example = "42";
int_example = parseInt(id);
var string_example = "42";

const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'postgres',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432
});

var query = "INSERT INTO data (int,string) VALUES (int_example,string_example);
client.connect()
    .then(() => console.log("Connection a la base de données réussie"))
    .then(() => console.log("Nos commandes:"))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
    .then(() => client.query(query))
```

I get this kind of error : "{ error: column "int_example" does not exist"
and i'm not sure if the string_example works as well... Seems I can't use type var or i'm doing something wrong please tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways to put variables in JS strings:

1. concatenation

```
var query = "INSERT INTO data (int,string) VALUES (" + int_example + ",'" + string_example + "');";
```

2. using template literals (recommended)

```
var query = `INSERT INTO data (int,string) VALUES (${int_example},'${string_example}');`
```

right now your query does not contain values of int_example and string_example and it's just their names.

Comment: i get { error: syntax error at or near "$" with using template literals

Comment: make sure you put backticks (`) correctly.

Comment: Oh! Thank you seems that ' is not same as ` that's why it didn't work, but now I have { error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "commande_pkey" do you have any idea ?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448340/postgresql-duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint) check this.

Comment: I think it's because i'm trying to INSERT INTO data (int_data) VALUES (${int_example}) but my int_data is a primarey key

Comment: well yes, primary keys should be unique. so if you for example have a row in your table with int_data = 1 you can't insert any other row with the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues results from your query string. The values of int_example and string_example are not present in your query.

You can fix the issue by either using [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation) or [string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition#string_concatenation)

You solution will be to use one of the below options:

String Interpolation:

```
var query = `INSERT INTO data (int,string) VALUES (${int_example},${string_example})`;
```

String Concatenation:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO data (int,string) VALUES (" + int_example + "," + string_example + ")";
```

> Note: Whenever you create a string from a string and a number/int the
> result is a string. Number/int is converted into a string when
> concatenating.

Comment: i get { error: syntax error at or near "$" with String interpolation