# duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_user_governments"

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to insert a record with many to many relationship in EfCore to postgres table

When adding a simple record to **Users**...it works but when I introduced 1:N with User_Governments

It started giving me duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_user_governments"

I have tried a few things:

> SELECT MAX(user_governments_id) FROM user_governments;
> SELECT nextval('users_gov_user_id_seq');

This keeps incrementing everytime I run it in postgres..but the issue does not go

I am inserting it as follows:

```
User user = new();
            user.Organisation = organisation;
            user.Name = userName;
            user.Email = email;
            user.IsSafetyDashboardUser = isSafetyFlag;

            if (isSafetyFlag)
            {
                List<UserGovernment> userGovernments = new List<UserGovernment>();

                foreach (var govId in lgas)
                {
                    userGovernments.Add(new UserGovernment()
                    {
                        LocalGovId = govId,
                        StateId = 7                            
                    });
                    
                }

                user.UserGovernments = userGovernments;

            }


            _context.Users.Add(user);

            int rows_affected = _context.SaveChanges();
```

Table and column in db is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_governments
(
    user_government_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    state_id integer NOT NULL,
    local_gov_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_user_governments PRIMARY KEY (user_government_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_governments_local_govs_local_gov_id FOREIGN KEY (local_gov_id)
        REFERENCES local_govs (local_gov_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_governments_states_state_id FOREIGN KEY (state_id)
        REFERENCES states (state_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_governments_users_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I have also tried running following command as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448340/postgresql-duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint) post

```
SELECT SETVAL((SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('user_governments', 'user_government_id')), (SELECT (MAX("user_government_id") + 1) FROM "user_governments"), FALSE);
```

but I get error:

> ERROR: relation "user_governments" does not exist

Comment: You last command should work. You can test it on dbfiddle. my example(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c9e7e4a7e8670196adb988b180446e61) You probably have schema visibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I did not build the model correctly.

The user_government table had an incremental key, but I had defined the model as follows

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserGovernment>()
   .HasKey(bc => new { bc.UserId, bc.LocalGovId });
```

I replaced it with:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGovernment>()
   .HasKey(bc => new { bc.UserGovernmentId});
```

****The Journey :)****

Initially I found out that once I commented the following line

```
_context.UserGovernments.AddRange(userGovernments);
```

It just inserted data with user_government_id as 0
Then I tried manually giving a value to user_government_id and it also went successfully, this lead me to check my modelbuilder code!!

Answer (score 2):

IDENTITY is an table integrated automatic increment. No needs to use PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE wich is dedicated for SEQUENCES that is another way to have increment outside the table. So you cannot use a query like :

```
SELECT SETVAL((SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('user_governments', 'user_government_id')), 
(SELECT (MAX("user_government_id") + 1) FROM "user_governments"), FALSE)
```

If your purpose is to assigne the seed for an IDENTITY, the ways to do that is :

You must use a syntax like this one :

```
ALTER TABLE user_governments
   ALTER COLUMN user_government_id RESTART WITH (select Max(user_government_id) + 1 from user_governments);
```

Comment: I just want to insert from my application successfully (preferably without changing db) but the error is probably leading me to change the db

Comment: It looks like the `(select` subquery syntax is no longer supported, but thanks for this answer! I was able to get it working just by putting in the correct number—in my case 19. So like this: `RESTART WITH 19`.